# Should I use CUDA here?

Tags: cuda

I have to multiply a very small sized matrix ( size - 10x10 ) with a vector several times 50000 to 100000 times ( could even be more than that). This happens for 1000 different matrices (could be much more). Would there be any significant performance gain by doing this operation on CUDA.

Comment: How many of the gemv operations can be done simultaneously? That is the key to knowing whether the GPU will be of any benefit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's an ideal task for the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to multiply a single matrix with a vector 50K times and each multiplication is prerequisite to the previous then don't use CUDA. It's a serial problem, best suites for CPU. However if each multiplication is independent you can multiply them simultaneously on CUDA.

The only case where your program will give tremendous speedup is when each vector multiplication iteration is independent  to the data of other iterations. This way you'll be able to launch 50K or more iterations simultaneously by launching equal number of threads.

Comment: Matrix multiplication is associative.

Comment: This didn't deserve a downvote IMO. Jawad did say, "if". I did assume, in my reply, that the question was about the standard BLAS type of vector-matrix multiplication. Of course, in the unlikely case that you actually need to multiply a matrix with the same vector 50k times, you can get the exponential of the vector and do a single multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly you're doing, then yes, this could be done very quickly on a GPU, but you might have to run your own kernel to get some good performance from it.

Without knowing more about your problem, I can't give you too much advice. But I could speculate on a solution:

If you're taking one vector and multiplying it by the same matrix several thousand times, you would be much better of finding the closed form of the matrix to an arbitrary power. You can do this using the Cayley–Hamilton theorem or the Jordan canonical form.

I can't seem to find an implementation of this from a quick googling, but considering I did this in first year linear algebra, it's not too bad. Some info on the Jordan normal form, and raising it to powers can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Powers and the transformation matrices of it are just a matrix of eigenvectors, and the inverse of that matrix.

Say you have a matrix A, and you find the Jordan normal form J, and the transformation matrices P, P^-1, you find

A^n = P J^n P^-1

I can't seem to find a good link to an implementation of this, but computing the closed form of a 10x10 matrix would be significantly less time consuming than 50,000 matrix multiplications. And an implementation of this would probably run much quicker on a CPU.

If this is your problem, you should look into this.